# Get access to databases folder

Tags: android, database, aes, android-sqlite, android-file

I want to get access to `databases` folder on my device, because it contains DB File, which I want to encrypt using AES algorithm (and decrypt before calling `SQLiteOpenHelper` class). Is there any way to get access to `databases` folder in `/data/data/com.myname.mypackage` and do some file-system operations?

Google, unfortunately, didn't help me in such case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) gives you your /data/data/ - and you can then just access the `databases/my_sql.db` file directly.

Be weary about hardcoding paths.

Comment: Ok, thank you for help. I will test this method, and accept your answer in ... (estimated time 3 minuts :-))